# Issue with checkbox listener in multifield

Tags: javascript, jquery, aem

I have a multifield component with a 1 checkbox in each item. I am adding a listener so that if one check box is checked all others should be unchecked automatically. I am writing the listener with jquery. When I check the next item in multifield, the functionality works fine, however, it doesn't work when I check a previous checkbox in the multifield item.

whats around with this code:

```
Check = 

function(e) {
   $("input[name='./isActive']").each(function () {
    if($(this).attr('id') !== e.id && $(this).attr('checked') && e.getValue() !== false) {
     if (confirm('Do you want to replace Alert message?')) {
      $(this).removeAttr('checked');
      return;
     } else {
      e.setValue(false);
      return;
     }
    }
   });
 }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Hope this resolve your issue 
[**JS FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.multiChecks').change(function() {        
        if($(this).prop('checked')){
            $('.multiChecks').not(this).removeAttr('checked');
        }
    }); });
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.multiChecks').change(function() {  
  var index = $( '.multiChecks' ).index( this );
  if($(this).prop('checked')){
   $('.multiChecks:gt('+index+')').removeAttr('checked');
   $('.multiChecks:;t('+index+')').removeAttr('checked');
  }
 });
});
```